# SQL Server - Insert row if new; Update if exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given:

Master Table:

```
A  B  C
a1 b1 NULL
a3 b2 NULL
```

New_Row Table:

```
A  B  C
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
```

Desired Output:

```
A  B  C 
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
a3 b2 NULL
```

I need a query that compares each columns between the Master Table and New_Row Table, and either updates the Master Table rows if all other columns in that row is identical or inserts a new row if the other columns in that row are different.

In the above example, the first row from the New_Row Table matches with the first row in the Master Table with the exception of the NULL value (assume Master Table is missing this data) so c1 is populated in the desired output. The second row from the New_Row Table doesn't match with any of the rows in the Master Table (as there is no a3 b2 rows in the Master), so it gets inserted in the desired output as a new row.

How would I write this query?

Comment: Have you read about [Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Is there a unique key on the table? How does one compare the rows in `New_Row` to those in `Master`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So without a unique key on either of your tables, this is a little dicier, but still doable.  You can do this either with a `MERGE` statement, or an explicit transaction. Which one you use is largely up to you. Personally I'm not a huge fan of `MERGE` because I find the syntax clunky and it can have some weird behaviors, but that's up to you. Also, i'm not sure what if any unique constraints exist on the table(s) but if there are none, and duplicates are possible, you may want to avoid `MERGE` as it doesn't play nicely with updating non-unique data sets.

With either approach, you also need to be careful how you're handling `NULL` values. If you just do a straight comparison (e.g. `t.c = s.c`) and one of the columns is null, that will *never* evaulate as true (since a `null` never equals anything; even another `null`). If that's something you care about, you'd need to either replace the nulls with a placeholder value (say, `isnull(t.c, '') = isnull(s.c, '')` or ad an additional check for whether the column(s) are null (e.g. `(t.c is null or s.c is null or t.c = s.c)`
**Setup Data**

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#New') is not null drop table #Master
create table #Master
(
    a varchar(10),
    b varchar(10),
    c varchar(10)
)

if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#new') is not null drop table #new
create table #new
(
    a varchar(10),
    b varchar(10),
    c varchar(10)
)

insert into #master
values ('a1', 'b1', null), ('a2', 'b2', null)

insert into #new
values ('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a2', 'b2', 'c2')
```

**Method 1: MERGE**

```
    merge into #master t -- target
using #new s --source
    on t.a = s.a
        and t.b = s.b
        and t.c = s.c
when not matched by target then insert
    (
        a,
        b,
        c
    )
    values
    (
        s.a,
        s.b,
        s.c
    )
when matched then update
    set c = s.c;
```

**Method 2: Explicit Transaction**

```
begin tran

    update t
    set c = s.c
    from #master t -- target
    inner join #new s -- source
        on t.a = s.a
            and t.b = s.b
            and t.c = s.c

    insert into #master
    (
        a,
        b,
        c
    )
    select
        s.a,
        s.b,
        s.c
    from #new s -- source
    left outer join #master t --target
        on s.a = t.a
            and s.b = t.b
            and s.c = t.c
    where t.a is null

commit tran
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server supports the `MERGE` statement to perform `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` actions in a single query.

You can find details on this statement here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

```
MERGE [master_table] AS TARGET
USING [new_row_table] AS SOURCE
ON (TARGET.A = SOURCE.A) AND (TARGET.B = SOURCE.B)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET TARGET.C = SOURCE.C
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (A, B, C)
    VALUES (SOURCE.A, SOURCE.B, SOURCE.C);
```

One caveat - `MERGE` is only supported in SQL Server 2008 and above.

Comment: The only thing I'd caution here is that we don't know what (if any) unique constraints exist on the table. That may just be an oversimplification of the format of the OP, but if there truly isn't a unique key on the table, merge with more than likely fail because it can't handle duplicate updates